# NHiberate count query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

In the NHiberante, I have this statement

```
 (from p in Session.Query<MyObject>() select p).Count();
```

is this equal to this ?

```
select count(*) from MyObject
```

assume object name is same as table name .

If the table data is huge, do we have a way to improve performance ?

thanks

Comment: If the table is really large, one way to improve performance would be to cache results or store a running total somewhere. Not much you can do to improve a rowcount as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can better use:

```
(from p in Session.Query<MyObject>() select p).LongCount();
```

SQLite query is:

```
select cast(count(*) as BIGINT) as col_0_0_ from MyObject myobject0_
```

You can create DBMS specific optimized queries with:

```
Session.CreateSQLQuery("sql query");
```

Questions about count optimizations:

[optimize mysql count query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400451/optimize-mysql-count-query)