# Estimate row count SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have more than 10 million rows. Counting the number of rows is too slow. I want to estimate the number of rows.

Current query is like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `database` WHERE `location` LIKE '%New York%'
```

This gives me the exact number and its too slow. What I want is something like this:

```
ESTIMATE count(*) FROM `database` WHERE `location` LIKE '%New York%'
```

Maybe this can be done by limiting the query to a subset of the table (every nth row or something).  Maybe there is a built-in function that can be used.

Edit: Perhaps I can limit the query to every nth row? and then multiple by n.

Edit2: I just tried counting every 10th row and then multiplying the count by ten, but there was no increase in speed, despite the fact that the auto-incrementing 'counter' is a primary key.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM database WHERE `location` LIKE '%Los Angeles%' and counter%10 = 0
```

Comment: there isn't such thing. you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400451/optimize-mysql-count-query  but if you have  a auto_incrm3ent why not use the max  as estimate

Comment: Right, I can simply add "WHERE COUNTER > 100 and COUNTER < 200" to get a sample of 100 rows. The problem with that is that I would be focusing on a particular part of the table which may not be representative. Is there a way to get every nth row?

Comment: If that is what you really need on a regular basis, run a counter with after triggers, it costs some time but you have quick an answer, count are always bad, and you must consider if you needed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance of COUNT(*) is not the biggest performance problem in this case. The performance cannot be improved, because your search condition `LIKE '%...%'` is bound to run a table-scan. It must examine every row in the table anyway, to check if it matches your condition.

Alternatives to make it quicker:

- Match the pattern using [fulltext indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead of `LIKE` predicates with wildcards
- Store the count and keep it updated as you add or change data, as the comment above suggests (but you'd need a separate counter for each possible search pattern)
- Get a more powerful computer
- Store less data

Comment: In some RDBMS products creating an index causes the system to keep/find number of records from the index structure very easily; would MySql have something like that (of course, after removing LIKE '%..')

Comment: Yes, values in an index are persistent, but MySQL does not have indexes that can store aggregated calculations like `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: MySQL's outdated MyISAM storage engine keeps a record of the total number of rows in the table, which makes `SELECT COUNT(*)` fast, _provided your query have no condition in the WHERE clause._ But InnoDB (the current default storage engine) does not support this, because the count of rows in a table varies due to transactions.

Answer (score 1):

This would run immensely faster if you have `INDEX(city)`:

```
WHERE `city` = New York'
```

This would run nearly as fast as that:

```
WHERE `city` = New York%'
```

If you currently have `location` as a combination of address, city, state, zip, then you may need to rethink the choice of having `location` in a single column.  Or go with a `FULLTEXT` index, as Karwin suggests.